# How to use Final Variables belonging to one block in another?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, final

```
final int a, b;

if (condition1) {
    a = get(dynamicValues);
    b = get(dynamicValues);
}

if (condition2) {
    int c = b + a;
    display(c);
}
```

In this type of code the compiler is asking to intialize a and b, which I can't do until the condition1 is met. and a and b being final is mandatory as the values of hours and minutes keep changing.
The above written code is very generalized just to give you an idea of my problem.

UPDATE: The problem here is `condition2` is one of the `else` conditions of `condition1`. So can't use else statements too. 
*Dynamic values* here are the values like "hrs and mins" which always change. when condition1 is met a and b are intialised with hrs and mins, condition2 will definitely happen after condition1 at some point of time. So the time difference between condition2 and condition1 needs to be calculated.

Comment: Why you need `a` and `b` final?

Comment: *"The problem here is condition2 is one of the else conditions of condition1"* And how should that work? How should `a` and `b` initialized _and_ `else if(condition2)` (your code is a bit different here) be entered?

Comment: as I already said.. a and b are intialised with hrs and mins in my android code and the change in hrs and mins is also causing change in my a and b values. so I want them to final and note the time when condition1 is met.

Comment: when condition1 is met a and b are intialised, condition2 will definately happen after condition1 at some point of time. So the time difference between condition2 and condition1 needs to be calculated.

Answer (score 3):

if condition1 is false a and b remain not initialized. That's why the compiler is complaining. Add the else branch and it will compile correctly

```
if(condition1)
 {
  a=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  b=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 } else {
   a = 0;
   b = 0;
 }
```

Comment: The problem here is condition2 is one of the else conditions of condition1.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I have not understood your problem correctly :). It seems to me that perhaps it's easier to wrap up your 'final' variables into an immutable class. Then create an instance of such a class in 'condition1'. Here's what I mean...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ImmutableHourMinute {

    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    public ImmutableHourMinute(final int $a, final int $b){
        this.a = $a;
        this.b = $b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a ;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        // Requirements:
        // 1. Hour and minute are set at condition == 1;
        // 2. Hour and minutes must never be changed.
        System.out.println("Please type 'start':");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ImmutableHourMinute hourAndMinute = null; // Can be initialized properly later

        while(!scanner.nextLine().equals("quit")){
            System.out.println("Please enter condition (1 or 2):");
            int condition = scanner.nextInt();

            if(condition == 1){
                Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                int a = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int b = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                System.out.println(String.format("(Creating ImmutableHourMinute(a=%1$d, b=%2$d)", a, b));
                hourAndMinute = new ImmutableHourMinute(a, b);
            }else if (condition == 2){
                display(hourAndMinute.getA() + hourAndMinute.getB());
            }

            System.out.println("Please enter condition (1 or 2):");
        }

    }

    private static void display(final int displayValue){
        System.out.println(String.format("Displaying the time set in condition 1 :%1$d", displayValue));
    }
}
```

And here is a sample of the output:

```
$ java ImmutableHourMinute
Please type 'start':
start
Please enter condition (1 or 2):
1
(Creating ImmutableHourMinute(a=9, b=56)
Please enter condition (1 or 2):
Please enter condition (1 or 2):
2
Displaying the time set in condition 1 :65
```

note : such and immutable class already exists(if you're using Java SE 8)...
    java.time.LocalDateTime

Comment: Hi, your answer works, but could you explain why you use $a? I remove $ it works either. I don't think java uses $ like C++.

Comment: Hi, I just used the $a so that it is utterly clear it's differernt from 'this.a'. just a personal preference. Sometimes scope/visibility rules of variables can cause confusion, so I try to avoid as much as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class time{
private int a=0;
private int b=0;

public int get()
  {
    return a+b;
  }

public void set()
  {
    this.a = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    this.b = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  }
}
```

In your main class, call the time class method(out of main method, at very begining),

```
public final Time t = new Time();
```

In main method:

```
if(condition1)
{
 t.set();
}
if(condition2)
 {
  display(t.get());
}
```

Comment: That didn't work because if a and b are initialized to zero and they are final, we cant change their values later (in conditions)

Comment: oooooh,sry misunderstood, I got your point. Let me explain, in JVM final variables should be initiated before any object creation. I modified the answer and try it.

Comment: Didn't work...by the way you forgot "int" after static and after correcting that...

ERROR: Illegal modifier for the variable a; only final is permitted

Comment: check it this time, it was mb, static should be claimed at very begining.

Comment: I want to use condition1's hour and minute values in a and b. your else if block will get condition2 values. and in my case condition1 will definitely occur before condition2 so.. else if doesn't help.

Comment: In your case, what is the relationship between condition1 and 2? If no relation, just remove "else". I think you can use a method to finish this function.I'll modify the answer.

Comment: a and b values will come from condition1 only and the calculation of c is done in condition2. these things are mandatory